# disabling selectbox in taghelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have Select Box Tag Helper

```
<select asp-for="DiscountTypeIndex" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DiscountType>()" @(@Model.Id>0 ? "disabled" : "")>
                                        </select>
```

I want if the Model.id is greater than zero , it would be disbaled, but the above code doesn't work

Comment: Firstly, you need add `disable="xxxxx"`, then be sure the `Model.Id` is type of int and conains value which is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<select asp-for="DiscountTypeIndex" class="form-control" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<DiscountType>()" 
    disabled="@(@Model.Id>0 ? "disabled" : "")">
</select>
```